# Как лучше организовать функцию

Tags: c++, функции, исключения, code-style

Есть такой код:

```
template<class __T>
class IdContainer
{
    std::vector<__T> unorderedIds_;

public:
    __T getNext() {
        auto _it = unorderedIds_.begin();

        if (_it != unorderedIds_.end()) {
            __T _id = *_it;
            unorderedIds_.erase(_it);
            return _id;
        }

        throw std::runtime_error("---");
    };
}
```

то бишь в случае если вектор пуст я выбрасываю исключение, а если там что-то есть возвращаю первый элемент. Возможно лучше сделать так:

```
bool getNext(__T& id) {
    auto _it = unorderedIds_.begin();

    if (_it != unorderedIds_.end()) {
        id = *_it;
        unorderedIds_.erase(_it);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Еще я вижу вариант с возвратом указателя:

```
__T* getNext() {
    return _id;
    or
    return nullptr;
}
```

но это прям перебор, выделять какой-нибудь int в куче.

Может есть и другие варианты которые я упускаю. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше написать эту функцию. Ее идея в том что она должна выдать нам первый id иначе дать понять что id закончились.

Comment: если `c++17` на столе, то ты скорей всего ищешь [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer , std::optional идеально подходит, но тогда у меня вопрос немного не по теме. С новыми стандартами приходят новые приколы типа optional, стоит ли использовать эти самые новые приколы вместо старых, ведь тот же optional я так понимаю не встроить в с++11. Этот код нельзя будет использовать в программах с более низким стандартом. Я понимаю что это вопрос того что требуется от библиотеки, но все же, как часто вы или ваши коллеги используете optional вместо его альтернатив (например тех что я описал в вопросе).

Comment: @ArtemiiSelyankin -  c++17 существует уже 4 года и поддержан всеми мейнстримными компиляторами. Если вы вынуждены сидеть на старье, у вашего работодателя и проекта, с большой долей вероятности, большие проблемы. (Например, в коде такой костылятник из UB, что нельзя просто взять и парой кликов перекинуть его на свежий компилятор).
Далее, для любителей старины, есть чуть менее удобный boost::optional.
Но этот вопрос опять сводится к ответу "все зависит от соглашений, принятых на проекте".

Comment: @Fat-Zer , Спасибо. Это то, что я хотел услышать.

Comment: `__T` - зарезервированное имя (из-за `__`), и использовать его - UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , я правильно понял что все имена начинающиеся на _ и __ зарезервированны? А зарезервированны ли имена оканчивающиеся на _ и __ ?

Comment: Не совсем. Вот тут есть описание: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3

Comment: Вы пишите *"как лучше"*, однако не приводите никаких критериев, по которым оценивается хорошесть функции. Соответственно вам не смогут дать ответ.

Comment: @user7860670 , согласен, нужно было более ясно это описать. Какой то конкретный критерий мне сложно было тут выделить, потому в самом конце я написал что должна делать функция - "она должна выдать нам первый id иначе дать понять что id закончились". Вот меня и интересует вопрос как бы это сделали более опытные программисты.

Comment: Ну более опытные программисты сразу бы обратили внимание на то, что удалять из вектора первый элемент - это самый плохой вариант и если эта операция будет выполнятся часто, то контейнер надо было бы поменять, а также на то, что выполняется излишнее копирование элемента, вместо перемещения. А вот должна ли функция возвращать код ошибки или optional или кидать исключения - это уже определяется тем, как задан интерфейс этой функции, а интерфейс функции определяется внешними факторами, которые в вопросе не приведены. Соответственно в этом плане опытные программисты вам ничем не помогут.

Comment: @user7860670 , спасибо за замечания, учту. А касательно вопроса, Fat-Zer и gbg еще в коментариях дали нужный мне ответ. Я еще немного подожду и выберу ответ. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Почему бы на добавить в класс переменную - `size_t first;`, которая индексирует первый элемент в векторе и не возвращать адрес соответствующего элемента вектора, увеличивая затем `first`? Если же `first == unorderedIds_.size()`, то возвращаете 0. imho это намного более эффективное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть целых 4 (вместе с `optional`) варианта решения данной проблемы, и все 4 варианта - хорошие.

Выбор конкретного варианта зависит от большого количества факторов:

1. От соглашений, принятых на проекте
2. От смысла выполняемой операции - *обычно*, исключение кидается, когда происходит *ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНАЯ СИТУАЦИЯ*, а программисты стараются не пускать обычную логику через исключения. Но это скорее вопрос соглашений, принятых на проекте.
3. Какие лучше выбрать соглашения для проекта?

- Если вы учитесь, вы должны знать и понимать все варианты
- Если вы начинаете новый проект в составе команды, вы будете принимать совместное решение.
- Если решение должны принимать лично вы, ориентируйтесь на свой опыт. Если опыта нет - у вас учебный проект, см. пункт выше (вам следует изучить все варианты).

Comment: Я так понимаю, (2) делают не только из-за соглашений, но и потому что исключения не особо быстро работают.

Comment: Вот тут есть интересное чтиво, которое подверждает ваши слова - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836329/5533854

Comment: Минусующие приглашаются в коментарии с аргументами.

Comment: *"данной проблемы"* - какой проблемы? В вопросе ни о какой проблеме не упоминается. *"все 4 варианта - хорошие"* - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306040/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e#comment2305786_1306040

Comment: Они *хорошие*, потому что работают и не приводят к UB на месте. А также все 4 успешно практикуются в индустрии.

Comment: В вопросе заявлена конкретная проблема - как вернуть из функции не только то что она может вернуть, но и ошибку.

Comment: *"как вернуть из функции не только то что она может вернуть, но и ошибку."*- извините, но это ваши отсебятина. В вопросе ОП рассматривает варианты "*Возможно лучше*" чем исходный с выбрасыванием исключения, но так как нигде не уточняется, что же он имеет ввиду под "лучше", то будут ли такие варианты лучше или нет, и нужны ли они там вообще - не известно. Собственно я бы предложил варианты получше с выкидыванием исключения, но воздержусь от ответа, так как вопрос мутный.

Answer (score -2):

Если у вас нет возможности перейти на новый компилятор и стандарт C++17, то вполне можно закодировать аналог std::optional, это просто, вот для примера я попробовал закодировать подобный класс:

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://godbolt.org/z/ohqadPe91)

```
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class Optional {
public:
    Optional() {}
    ~Optional() { Destruct(); }
    template <typename Q>
    Optional(Q && v) { Construct(std::forward<Q>(v)); }
    template <typename Q>
    Optional & operator = (Q && v) { return Construct(std::forward<Q>(v)); }
    Optional(Optional const & other) { Replace(other.has_val, other.val); }
    Optional & operator = (Optional const & other) {
        return Replace(other.has_val, other.val);
    }
    Optional(Optional && other) { Replace(other.has_val, std::move(other.val)); }
    Optional & operator = (Optional && other) {
        return Replace(other.has_val, std::move(other.val));
    }
    bool has_value() const { return has_val; }
    operator bool() const { return has_val; }
    T & value() {
        if (!has_val)
            throw std::runtime_error("Optional doesn't contain value!");
        return val;
    }
    T const & value() const { return const_cast<Optional&>(*this).value(); }
    T & operator * () { return val; }
    T const & operator * () const { return val; }
    T * operator -> () { return &val; }
    T const * operator -> () const { return &val; }
    void reset() { Destruct(); }
    template <typename ... Args>
    T & emplace(Args && ... args) {
        Construct(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return val;
    }
private:
    template <typename ... Args>
    Optional & Replace(bool has, Args && ... args) {
        return has ? Construct(std::forward<Args>(args)...) : Destruct();
    }
    template <typename ... Args>
    Optional & Construct(Args && ... args) {
        Destruct();
        new (&val) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        has_val = true;
        return *this;
    }
    Optional & Destruct() {
        if (has_val) {
            val.~T();
            has_val = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    bool has_val = false;
    struct Dummy {};
    union {
        Dummy dummy;
        T val;
    };
};
```

А так вообще я думаю что просто возвращать bool из функции вида `bool getNext(__T& id)` как вы предложили это вполне подходящий и простой вариант.

Варианты с возвращением указателя или исключением тоже рабочие, но если это высокопроизводительный участок кода, то лучше их не использовать, они сильно замедлят код. `bool` вариант при этом не испортит производительности.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127605/discussion-on-answer-by-arty----).