# Когда принято бросать исключения в C++?

Tags: c++, исключения, code-style

В какой-то статье по code style от Google я прочитал что они вообще стараются не использовать исключения и тогда я задался вопросом, а в каких ситуациях обычно **принято** бросать исключения. Я сейчас могу вспомнить лишь один вариант где они будут кстати - конструктор. В остальных функциях и методах, вместо исключения можно, как вариант, возвращать false или nullptr. Смысл в том что в других местах бросок исключения можно заменить чем то другим, а часто чем то более удобным. Меня интересует когда **принято** бросать исключения.

Comment: Обычно в исключительных ситуациях исключения бросают. Когда что-то пошло не так.

Comment: По-хорошему - всегда, когда не в состоянии обработать ошибку самостоятельно. Потому что "ошибочное" возвращаемое значение далеко не всегда можно вернуть (ну, тупой пример - `bool male(const char* name)` - возвращает `true` для мужчины, `false` для женщины, и что вернуть, если такого человека нет в базе?), а при возврате его могут и не проверить. А при проверке  в случае десятка последовательных вызовов выходят такие "сопли", что... Словом, для того и придумали исключения, чтоб ими пользоваться :)

Comment: Дубликат-бубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306040/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e

Comment: @gbg , это не дубликат. Там суть вопроса в том как нужно организовать функцию, а исключение приводится как один из возможных вариантов. Тут я пытаюсь разобраться в вопросе исключений более подробно. Ну тип 1 вопрос - 1 тема для рассуждений.

Comment: Оба вопроса на грани возможности дать однозначный ответ, основанный на фактах и цитатах, а не на мнениях.  Более того, они провоцируют теоретические споры, что также не приветсвуется правилами ресурса.

Почему это *бубликат* - да потому что фактически, все сведется к теоретическим спорам между return false; и применению исключений на все случаи жизни, что опять же будет скорее процессом высказывания мнений, чем выдачей однозначного ответа на все случаи жизни. Я конечно попробовал написать максимально обтекаемо, теперь вот сижу, обтекаю от минусов.

Comment: Когда важна скорость, то убирают проверку состояния очень редко появляющихся ошибок и запускают исключение. С другой стороны обработка исключений увеличивает размер кода, и если ситуация случается часто, то проще один `if` поставить.

Comment: gbg , в этом и смысл. Иногда нужно услышать не совет, а мнение. Я понимаю что оба эти вопроса очень такие себе, но потому я их и задал. Мне нужно услышать мнение тех кто шарит больше меня. Я могу найти ответ на любой интересущий меня вопрос в инете, но вот что найти сложнее так это мнение нескольких опытных программистов на конкретный, интересующий меня вопрос. И в целом я получил ответы которые меня удовлетворили на оба вопроса. Но я еще посмотрю что напишут другие. Не срача ради, а ради мнений. Спасибо за хорошие ответы.

Comment: @ArtemiiSelyankin Вопросы, которые предполагают ответ в виде мнений, являются оффтопиком на этом сайте. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: imho концепция исключений вообще не подходит для сколь-нибудь сложных и ответственных систем (maintenance разваливается), лучше уж использовать siglongjmp()